# Name of the formula which links an event with an alternatives' system

Tags: probability, notation

Given an event $B$ and a system of alternatives (I hope this is the right name in english, otherwise tell me the right one please) $(A_i)_{i=1}^n$, the following formula is valid:

$$
P(B \, | \, \Omega) = P(B \, | \, \Omega \, \cap \, A_1) \, P(A_1 \, | \, \Omega) +
... +
P(B \, | \, \Omega \, \cap \, A_n) \, P(A_n \, | \, \Omega)
$$

I'd like to know the english name of the above formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "system of alternatives" is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) and the probability equation is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  (In the present case, it is expressed with all events explicitly conditioning on $\Omega$.)

Comment: Hello @Ben thank you very much for your precious help.

Comment: can you give a look also at this question please? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/557996/name-of-the-formula-which-links-the-expectation-of-a-random-variable-with-the-su