# Name of the formula which links the expectation of a random variable with the summation of the product between conditioned expectation and probability

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, terminology

I'd like to know the English name of the following property of the expectation ($X$ random variable; $(A_i)_{i=1}^n$ partition of a set):

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum \limits _{i = 1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[X | A_i] \,\, P(A_i)
\end{equation}

where:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X | A_i] = \sum \limits _{k \in \mathbb{R}} k \,\, P(X = k | A_i)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first equation is the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).  The second equation is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition) of the conditional expected value of a discrete random variable.  (In this latter equation you have used a summation over an uncountable set, which is unusual in probability and statistics; while this is well-defined, it is rather off-putting in this context, and it would be better to take the sum over the support/integers.)

Comment: +1 The sum *does* make sense whenever the conditional distribution of $X$ is discrete -- but I think you are right to call out the potential for error in the general case.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Ben I forgot to write that I'm considering discrete random variables.

Comment: @Ben In higher mathematics there is no ambiguity.  I recall Serge Lang discusses this in his *Algebra:* sums of functions over uncountable sets are well-defined when at most a countable number of the values are nonzero and the sum converges absolutely (which is the case for any discrete probability measure).

Comment: I'm just telling you what is conventional in mathematics.  You are always free to ignore it.  But please don't assert it "doesn't make sense" when indeed sense has been made of it!

Comment: @whuber: Okay, you've convinced me that I have overstated my objection.  With some trepidation, I've edited the answer to soften my objection to summation over the reals.

Comment: (I already upvoted the answer ;-).)